# No Module named "Bio"

Tags: python, module, biopython

I'm on OSX and I can't hardly find anything for mac users about this. I'm using Visual Studio Code, pip 21.3.1, and python 3.8 for reference.

I'm using "pip install biopython" and everything installs. In fact, the little word on VSCode turns green and everything. There's no warning. But when I run it from the terminal, there's an error that says the module doesn't exist. I added the exact path to the module to my PATH, still nothing. No idea what to do and I'm losing my mind. If I did not have to use this for a class, I would scrap the whole thing. I've uninstalled, reinstalled, moved it to different places, everything I can think of.

I would show the code, but I don't have any yet. I'm just trying to get it to import.

I just need help from someone who's more educated than me about this.

Comment: Are you using the correct python interpreter? You can change it by pressing Control + shift + P in VS code then type Python interpreter. From there you can select the proper one.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)